# Android Webview image upload from gallery and camera, camera not working

Tags: android, file-upload, camera, android-webview

I have been searching all related posts here regarding this problem, but I cannot figure out, why the image upload does not work (testing on device with Android 8), when taking a picture from my camera. Gallery upload works fine as expected.

In the activity result i get a path to the image in the cache directory (variable mCameraPhotoPath), but it seems that the result or the website cannot access this file or maybe there is an empty image file in there.

Taking and uploading the image via google chrome directly on the device works, so I think the problem is not on the website side.

Here are my permissions

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<!-- for new versions api 21+-->
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA2" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

this is my application definition

```
 <application
    android:name="***"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Android">

    <!-- added fileprovider support -->
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
```

Then I added an xml folder in the res directory with a file called file_path.xml and added the content

```
<paths>
  <cache-path
    name="mediaimages"
    path="./">
  </cache-path>
</paths>
```

And this is my activity code

```
private var mUploadCallbackAboveL: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>? = null
private var mUploadCallbackBelow: ValueCallback<Uri?>? = null
private var imageUri: Uri? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {   
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  // webview definition 
  myWebView.webChromeClient = initChromeWebViewClient()
  myWebView.webViewClient = initWebViewClient()
  myWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
  myWebView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
  myWebView.settings.allowFileAccess = true
  myWebView.settings.allowContentAccess = true
  myWebView.settings.supportZoom()
  myWebView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
  myWebView.settings.userAgentString = "android"
  myWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)

  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
      myWebView.settings.mixedContentMode = 0
  }
}

private fun initChromeWebViewClient() : WebChromeClient {
    webChromeViewClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
        /**
         * API > = 21 (Android 5.0.1) calls back this method
         */
        override fun onShowFileChooser(
            webView: WebView?,
            valueCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>,
            fileChooserParams: FileChooserParams?
        ): Boolean {
            //(1) when the method calls back, it indicates that the version API > = 21. In this case, assign the result to muploadcallbackabovel to make it! = null
            mUploadCallbackAboveL = valueCallback
            takePhoto()
            return true
        }
    }
    return webChromeViewClient
}

@Override
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        val file: File = File(imageUri!!.toString())
        val file_size = (file.length() / 1024).toString().toInt()
        //After the above two assignment operations (1) and (2), we can decide which processing method to adopt according to whether its value is empty
        if (mUploadCallbackBelow != null) {
            chooseBelow(resultCode, data);
        } else if (mUploadCallbackAboveL != null) {
            chooseAbove(resultCode, data);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText (this, "an error occurred.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Method which creates and starts the chooser Intent

```
private fun takePhoto() {
    //Adjust the camera in a way that specifies the storage location for taking pictures
    var photoFile : File? = null
    val authorities : String = applicationContext.packageName + ".provider"
    try {
        photoFile = createImageFile()
        imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, authorities, photoFile)
    } catch(e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    val captureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri)
    val Photo = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
    val chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(Photo, "Image Chooser")
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, arrayOf<Parcelable>(captureIntent))
    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_CODE)
}

@Throws(IOException::class)
  private fun createImageFile(): File {
    val imageFileName = "JPEG_" + SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())
    return File(applicationContext.cacheDir.toString() + File.separator + imageFileName + ".jpg")
}
```

method to handle Android L+ results

```
private fun chooseAbove(resultCode : Int, data : Intent?) {
    if (RESULT_OK == resultCode) {
        updatePhotos()

        if (data != null) {
            //Here is the processing of selecting pictures from a file
            val results : Array<Uri>
            val uriData : Uri? = data.data
            if (uriData != null) {
                results = arrayOf(uriData)
                mUploadCallbackAboveL!!.onReceiveValue(results)
            } else {
                mUploadCallbackAboveL!!.onReceiveValue(null)
            }
        } else {
            if (imageUri != null) {
                mUploadCallbackAboveL!!.onReceiveValue(arrayOf(imageUri!!))
            }
        }
    } else {
        mUploadCallbackAboveL!!.onReceiveValue(null)
    }
    mUploadCallbackAboveL = null
}
```

Edit:
Updated code to working code up until Android 10, Android 11 does not work. Picture is taken, but not shown in Webviews Input.
It seems the Fileprovider approach does not work or something is misconfigured for Android 11.

Comment: `takePictureIntent!!.putExtra("PhotoPath, ...` That makes no sense. No Camera app will look at that extra.

Comment: `Uri.fromFile(photoFile)` For Android 5 ok. But not for Android 7+.

Comment: `mCameraPhotoPath` What is the value in onActivityResult? null? That empty file you did create yourself. Not the Camera app. No need to create an empty file. Only a File instance.

Comment: Use FileProvider instead.

Comment: @blackapps the path in onActivityResult is a path to the cache directory
file:/data/user/0/*bundlename*/cache/JPEG_20210912_184659_6360279621712686910.jpg
The filesize of this file in onActivityResult is 0, I think this is already a bad sign?

What would be the correct way for Android 7+ systems to get the Uri for the file?

Comment: I have added a second method which just creates a file instance, but still the file is not uploaed. I also added the resulting filepath from the method in the question above.
Do I set the Extra in the intent in a wrong way?
takePictureIntent!!.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile))

Comment: You did not read my second comment? And if there is no file created by the Camera app....

Comment: I found this tutorial to upgrade the camera for 7+ Android https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ZxRTKvtfnY . The image Uri for the camera file is now: 
content://*package_name*.fileprovider/mediaimages/Pictures/JPEG_20210914_084836_.jpg when using the Fileprovider (according to the tutorial video).
still code runs through and calls the callback, but image is not sent back to webview.

Comment: `/data/user/0/<package>/cache/JPEG_20210913_181047_.jpg`

Comment: I updated the question and added the part for the FileProvider and removed some unrelated code.

Comment: `val file: File = File(imageUri!!.toString())
        val file_size = (file.length() / 1024).toString().toInt()`. That is nonsense as you can not use an Uri instance for the File class. Better: `val file: File = photoFile;` And do not devide by 1024 while testing. Further you could just use a file manager app to see if the picture is valid. `Is the image created is the first we have to know` but you did not tell.. Please adapt your code. Probably you will find out that `photoFile==null` by the time the Camera app returns.` Check for null before use. Adapt your code please.

Comment: I found the issue! in the file_paths.xml file i added external-path, but this has to be cache-path now and in the createImageFile method the applicationContext.cacheDir has to be used. Now everything is working as expected!

Comment: sadly, I have to comment again. On Android 11 the approach from the answer below does not work anymore. Is there another new way necessary for android 11?

Comment: Hi, I adapted the code in the question to a working code up to  Android 10 for taking pictures, with all necessary steps in all files which need to be modified / created.
But on Android 11 this does not work anymore.

Comment: @Vario do you find a solution for android >= 11?

Answer (score 1):

Question was updated with working code.
Now chooser intent allows to select image from gallery or taken by the camera for Android +5 devices.

Main issue was, that no FileProvider was used and cache directory was not specified correctly in file_paths.xml file.

Thanks to @blackapps for help and guiding into the correct direction!